# When product of absolutely convergent is not absolutely convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\int f(x)$ and $\int g(x)$ be absolutely convergent on $[a,b)$. What $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ can I take in order to show that $\int f(x)g(x)$ is not absolutely convergent?

I know that it works for series, but for what functions does it break for integrals?

Answer (score 1):

let $f(x)=g(x)=x^{-1/2}$

then $\int_0^1|f(x)|dx=\int_0^1|g(x)|dx=2$, however, $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx$ diverges